# sql connnection error faced using tkinter, python only while editing/updating the table

Tags: python, sql, m

I get this message when i have created a table, i ask the user to edit their info and this error message pops up
I am using Windows 10
Xampp version 8.1.2
Tried reinstalling xampp but didnt work
Have triple checked the table name, database name etc. All are correct
Here's my code

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector as mysql
from tkinter import *
my_w = Tk()
my_w.state('zoomed')
my_w.resizable(0,0)
global b
my_command = mysql.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "", database = 
"employee_form")
#check bookamrks

def display():
    my_cursor=my_command.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT * FROM employee limit 0,10")
    my_cursor.execute(query)
    global b
    b=0 
    for employee in my_cursor: 
        for j in range(len(employee)):
            e = Label(my_w,width=10, text=employee[j],
                relief='solid', anchor="w")  
            e.grid(row=b, column=j) 
        
        editButton = Button(my_w,width=5, text='Edit',relief='solid', 
        anchor="w",command=lambda k=employee[0]:edit_data(k))  
        editButton.grid(row=b, column=17)     
        b=b+1
display()
def edit_data(id): 
    global b 

    row=my_command.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empId = %s", id)
    row.execute(query)
    s = row.fetchone() # row details as tuple

    StringName = StringVar(my_w)
    StringSurname = StringVar(my_w)
    Stringdate = StringVar(my_w)
    StringMonth = StringVar(my_w)
    StringYear = StringVar(my_w)
    StringGender = StringVar(my_w)
    StringMarital = StringVar(my_w)
    StringContact = StringVar(my_w)
    StringId = StringVar(my_w)
    StringSalary = StringVar(my_w)
    StringDesignation = StringVar(my_w)
    StringFlat = StringVar(my_w)
    StringRoad = StringVar(my_w)
    StringCity = StringVar(my_w)
    StringDistrict = StringVar(my_w)
    StringState = StringVar(my_w)
    StringCountry = StringVar(my_w)

    StringName.set(s[0])
    StringSurname.set(s[1]) 
    Stringdate.set(s[2])
     StringMonth.set(s[3])
    StringYear.set(s[4])
    StringGender.set(s[5])
    StringMarital.set(s[6])
    StringContact.set(s[7])
    StringId.set(s[8])
    StringSalary.set(s[9])
    StringDesignation.set(s[10])
    StringFlat.set(s[11])
    StringRoad.set(s[12])
    StringCity.set(s[13])
    StringDistrict.set(s[14])
    StringState.set(s[15])
    StringCountry.set(s[16])
    
    e1=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringName,width=10,state='disabled')
    e1.grid(row=i,column=0)
    e2=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringSurname,width=10)
    e2.grid(row=i,column=1)
    e3=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=Stringdate,width=10)
    e3.grid(row=i,column=2)
    e4=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringMonth,width=10)
    e4.grid(row=i,column=3)
    e5=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringYear,width=10)
    e5.grid(row=i,column=4)
    e6=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringGender,width=10)
    e6.grid(row=i,column=5)
    e7=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringMarital,width=10)
    e7.grid(row=i,column=6)
    e8=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringContact,width=10)
    e8.grid(row=i,column=7)
    e9=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringId,width=10)
    e9.grid(row=i,column=8)
    e10=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringSalary,width=10)
    e10.grid(row=i,column=9)
    e11=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringDesignation,width=10)
    e11.grid(row=i,column=10)
    e12=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringFlat,width=10)
    e12.grid(row=i,column=11)
    e13=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringRoad,width=10)
    e13.grid(row=i,column=12)
    e14=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringCity,width=10)
    e14.grid(row=i,column=13)
    e15=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringDistrict,width=10)
    e15.grid(row=i,column=14)
    e16=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringState,width=10)
    e16.grid(row=i,column=15)
    e17=tk.Entry(my_w,textvariable=StringCountry,width=10)
    e17.grid(row=i,column=16)

    b2 = tk.Button(my_w,text='Update',command=lambda: my_update(),
            relief='solid', anchor="w",width=5)  
    b2.grid(row=i, column=18) 
    def my_update(): # update record
        data=StringName.get(),StringSurname.get(),Stringdate.get(),StringMonth.get(),StringYear.get(),StringGender.get(),StringMarital.get(),StringContact.get(),StringId.get(),StringSalary.get(),StringDesignation.get(),StringFlat.get(),StringRoad.get(),StringCity.get(),StringDistrict.get(),StringState.get(),StringCountry.get())
        id=my_command.execute("UPDATE employee SET name=%s,surname=%s,date = %s,month=%s, year = %s,gender = %s, maritalStatus = %s, contactNumber = %s, salary = %s, designation = %s, flat = %s, road = %s, city = %s, district %s, state = %s, country = %s WHERE id=%s",data)
        messagebox.showinfo("Update", "Values Updates Successfully")
        for w in my_w.grid_slaves(b): # remove the edit row
            w.grid_forget()
        display()
my_command.commit()
my_command.close()
my_w.mainloop()
```

Now here's the traceback

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hrk_vnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Datafolder\HRK\Learning\Programming\Python\001_Cool\Form\edit.py", line 23, in 
<lambda>
    editButton = Button(my_w,width=5, text='Edit',relief='solid', anchor="w",command=lambda 
k=employee[0]:edit_data(k))
   File "E:\Datafolder\HRK\Learning\Programming\Python\001_Cool\Form\edit.py", line 30, in 
edit_data
    row=my_command.cursor()
    File "C:\Users\hrk_vnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
    packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 578, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
    mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

there are no more specific details
thank you

Comment: from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) MySQL was replaced with **MariaDB** on 19 October 2015 and beginning with XAMPP versions 5.5.30 and 5.6.14,[7] effectively altering the meaning of the acronym. which version of XAMPP are you using?

Comment: @LeiYang I am using XAMPP Version 8.1.2(OS: Windows)

Comment: can you please elaborate? Because all the connection code(mysql.connector in the start) which i have written work in other programs like deleting and adding rows, but its only showing error in this Thank you

Comment: @LeiYang do you mean i have to change this code? my_command = mysql.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "", database = 
"employee_form")

Comment: @LeiYang for using mariadb, is anything else to be needed/ installed?

Comment: using python or directly from mysql

Comment: yes i tried and yes it added a row in the collumn name(not this program)

Comment: @LeiYang  so mysql is working for al programs except this? Because all of my mysql.connector- python programs are connecting and working well except this one

Comment: @LeiYang  so can i try by switching networks? Are there chances it might work?

Comment: @LeiYang How can i user mysql command to validate? I am a beginner so i didnt understand it well. Can you elaborate it more? Thanks

Comment: @LeiYang i had seen a website to check mysql

Comment: I went to Sevices.msc but MySQL80 didnt show up, no process named mysql showed up

Comment: it should be available in `cmd` prompt.

Comment: i even typed mysql and mysql.connector(module name) in cmd, it shows its not there

Comment: 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: 'mysql.connector' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: maybe you only have server installed, you may need install [mysql shell](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/). before that find similiar thing in start menu.

Comment: do i have to change the path variable of sql?

Comment: you need to debug things yourself. your python client reports `MySQL Connection not available`, so you need prove `MySQL Connection is available` by some means (obviously you need some other tools other than python client, and mysql command line is the best option). then it is your own task to learn what mysql command is, how to install...

Comment: Ok i will revert back to u in an hour or so Thanks for the help! Appreciate it.